# rules engine for C++ code

Tags: c++, rules, rule-engine

I am looking for a Jess-like engine ( http://www.jessrules.com/jess/index.shtml ) but in unmanaged environment. I want something simple enough but possibly compliant with JSR-94. Any ideas?

Comment: Hans, what do u mean by the never ending graduate student project?:) I need it for a production system where we need to extract some rules without reinventing the wheel and at the same time falling int soft coding ( http://thedailywtf.com/articles/soft_coding.aspx)...

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/Version63Beta.html)?

> CLIPS is a forward-chaining rule-based
>   programming language written in C that
>   also provides procedural and
>   object-oriented programming
>   facilities.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the link, I looked at CLIPS, but it seems to be a little too big for what I need. It's a full-blown language which does not really simplify things for me.

Answer (score 0):

IBM probably charges an arm and a leg for it, but you should take a look at IBM's ILOG Rules (C++).

I've used ILOG JRules, which is the Java implementation.  It's not perfect, by any means, but once set up correctly it performs beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking for something similar to JESS then Steve's recommendation of CLIPS is the right answer. JESS was "inspired" by CLIPS and supports the exact same rule language.
If CLIPS is somehow "too big" for what you need, then JESS and ILOG are probably too big as well.